# Flexible distance learning Mathematics programme

Tags: education, self-learning, learning

I am looking for a flexible Mathematics degree programme from a reputable institution.

By flexible here I mean:

- Able to take the programme at one's own pace
- The option to complete the programme at a good institution
- Preferably 100% of the course is assessed through a written exam

So far, I am only able to find [this](http://www.londoninternational.ac.uk/courses/undergraduate/lse/bsc-mathematics-economics).

What other alternatives exists?

Thank you in advance for any recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Try the open distance learning intstitution, the University of South Africa .

http://www.unisa.ac.za/qualifications/index.asp?link=http://www.unisa.ac.za/qualifications/Navigation/CSET_ALL.html

Hope youthis helps

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question late, but nevertheless here is what I know of:

It is not too difficult to find BS programs in math fitting your criteria, and in fact, there is a public Q&A forum dedicated to distance learning programs, it is called degreeinfo.com in [*here*](http://www.degreeinfo.com/content/). Membership is open to public, this forum is centered on regionally accredited schools. You will get tons of info from there.

Hope this help and good luck!